# How to get the shapes in a docx drawing using XWPF (Apache POI)

Tags: apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I have a docx document with text and some shapes. I am able to get the drawings, but when I get a drawing, how can I get the Shapes in this drawing? For example I have the following code to parse my document:

```
  try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
     document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
     parseDocument(document);
  }
```

The `parseDocument(XWPFDocument document)` method has the following code (I used the answer to the following question: [How to get the drawings from the apache POI XWPFDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630688/how-to-get-the-drawings-from-the-apache-poi-xwpfdocument)):

```
   public void parseDocument(XWPFDocument document) throws Exception {
      Iterator<XWPFParagraph> it = document.getParagraphs().iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         XWPFParagraph paragraph = it.next();
         List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
         Iterator<XWPFRun> it2 = runs.iterator();
         while (it2.hasNext()) {
            XWPFRun run = it2.next();
            List<CTDrawing> drawings = getAllDrawings(run);
            if (!drawings.isEmpty()) {
               System.out.println("Found " + drawings.size() + " drawings");
               Iterator<CTDrawing> it3 = drawings.iterator();
               while (it3.hasNext()) {
                  CTDrawing drawing = it3.next();
                  visitDrawing(drawing);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private void visitDrawing(CTDrawing drawing) {
      List<CTInline> inlines = drawing.getInlineList();
      Iterator<CTInline> it = inlines.iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         CTInline inline = it.next();
         CTGraphicalObject graphic = inline.getGraphic();
         if (graphic != null) {
            CTGraphicalObjectData graphicData = graphic.getGraphicData();
            if (graphicData != null) {
               XmlCursor c = graphicData.newCursor();
               c.selectPath("./*");
               while (c.toNextSelection()) {
                  XmlObject o = c.getObject();
                  System.out.println(o);
               }
            }
         }
      }
      
      List<CTAnchor> anchors = drawing.getAnchorList();
      Iterator<CTAnchor> it2 = anchors.iterator();
      while (it2.hasNext()) {
         CTAnchor anchor = it2.next();
         CTGraphicalObject graphic = anchor.getGraphic();
         if (graphic != null) {
            CTGraphicalObjectData graphicData = graphic.getGraphicData();
            if (graphicData != null) {
               XmlCursor c = graphicData.newCursor();
               c.selectPath("./*");
               while (c.toNextSelection()) {
                  XmlObject o = c.getObject();
                  System.out.println(o);
               }
            }
         }
      }      
   }

   private static List<CTDrawing> getAllDrawings(XWPFRun run) throws Exception {
      CTR ctR = run.getCTR();
      XmlCursor cursor = ctR.newCursor();
      cursor.selectPath("declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' .//*/w:drawing");
      List<CTDrawing> drawings = new ArrayList<>();
      while (cursor.hasNextSelection()) {
         cursor.toNextSelection();
         XmlObject obj = cursor.getObject();
         CTDrawing drawing = CTDrawing.Factory.parse(obj.newInputStream());
         drawings.add(drawing);
      }
      return drawings;
   }
```

With both the inline and anchor drawings, the `XmlObject` element contains the shapes I can see it is the case in very simple exampleswhen I look at the printed content), but how do I get these shapes when I have the object?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "how do I get these shapes"? You get the XML that describes the shapes. There is nothing else you could get from the `*.docx` file.

Comment: My question is that I want to know which shapes I have in the XmlObject and their characteristics. Does it mean that I have to perform org.w3c.dom.Node node = o.getDomNode(); and then parse the content of the DOM node? XWPF does not provide an API at this level?

Comment: The `CTGraphicalObjectData` is the last object you can get. What this might contain depends on the kind of the shape. This might be a picture, a wordprocessing shape, a chart, a diagram, ... and so on. Each of them use own XML schemas and own classes. So yes, the only way to parse this content will be to get the pure `XmlObject`s and then to check what you got, using `getClass().getName()` and/or `instanceof` for example. Try `System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());` in your code. If you know what you have, you can cast the object appropriate and then use the methods of that casted class.